# Help identifying a board edge press-fit contact

Tags: pcb, connector

I'm working on a project involving a Becker car radio from the 1980s and I need some help identifying a part that is used inside. It's the gold press-fit contact shown below and it's used to make a right angle board-to-baord connection. The extruding part on each contact is pressed into a plated through hole on another PCB. The contacts themselves are through-hole soldered onto the host PCB with 2 pins each. The pitch on the board seems to be 2.5mm, but they are each a separate piece.

The project is to create a modified replacement board for the one pictured, so I have some flexibility for a different part, but it has to provide the same function.

I'm not sure if I'm searching the wrong thing or this is an obscure part, but I'm not having any luck finding a similar contact online. Any part numbers, names, or pointers would be appreciated, thanks!

[image: Becker 1480 Board edge contact pin front]

[image: Becker 1480 Board edge contact pin back]

Answer (score 3):

You may want to investigate this company. They make the type of pins shown here that are very close in application to what you are looking for. Depending upon the mating hole size these may work for you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The contacts pictured are very likely custom made for the manufacturer at that time some 3.5 decades ago. It seems unlikely that you will be able to find the exact equivalent today unless you had access to the original manufacturer's Bill of Materials with supplier names and part numbers.

My take on this is that you should consider adding a single row socket pin type header to the plated through holes of the mating part and then adjust the size of the replacement board to allow use of a soldered on header with 25mil square posts.

**Low Profile Single Row Socket Header:**

[image]

**Strip Pin Header Soldered to PCB Fingers:**

[image]